# How do I add secondary tabs to the user (profile) edit tab?

Tags: 8, users

In earlier versions of Drupal, there were categories of users which showed up as tabs on the user (profile) edit page, located at /user/{user}/edit. How can we define new tabs on this page in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tabs can be added to the user edit page as follows:

1) Define the route(s) for your tab(s) in [MODULE].routing.yml as normal:

```
[MODULE].something.user_defaults:
  path: '/user/{user}/edit/something'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\[MODULE]\Controller\SomeController::someSettingsTab'
    _title: 'Some Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'some permission'
    user: \d+
  options:
    parameters:
      user:
        type: entity:user
```

2) In [MODULE].links.task.yml, add your tab(s) as you would primary tabs, except rather than using `base_route`, use `parent_id`, and set it to (somewhat unintuitively) the user edit form tab key, which is defined in `user.links.task.yml` as `entity.user.edit_form` (same as the route name):

```
[MOUDLE].something.user_defaults:
  route_name: [MODULE].something.user_defaults
  parent_id: entity.user.edit_form
  title: Some Title
  weight: 10
```

3) You also need to define a tab for the user to switch back to, as tabs are only rendered if there are more than two tabs. In this case, we want to add a tab for the user edit form, using the user edit form route, again using the user edit form tab key:

```
[MODULE].entity.user.edit_form:
  route_name: entity.user.edit_form
  parent_id: entity.user.edit_form
  title: Profile
```

Comment: Step 2 here says `module.links.tasks.yml` but I think the `tasks` should be singular: `module.links.task.yml`. I don't see any `tasks.yml` files in core/contrib.

Comment: Updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this with a Views created page. and trying to add to Admin Content page. So step 1 and 3 not required. Step 2: ssc_custom.admin_orphaned_pages:
  title: Orphaned pages
  route_name: view.orphaned_pages.page_1
  parent_id: system.admin_content    - cant add a return here.. ughh... this does add a secondary task but when going to that page, the primary/secondary tabs disappear.